# Maximum # of up-to-date Prolog implementations with minimum overhead

Tags: installation, prolog, updates

This is not directly a question regarding Prolog code, but rather about installing, administrating, and updating Prolog implementations...

Ideally, **what I want** to have on my machine is:

- As many different Prolog implementations as possible
- At all times, the most current (development) versions should be available
- I might also want to have 2 or more versions side by side (stable / development)
- A minimum overhead for installation, administration, etc.

I want to choose which Prolog implementation I use today after I start my machine up.

What can I do? What have **you** tried in this respect? I run Linux. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I also use Linux. To get the latest anything, I pull and compile from their respository (which they should cite if they have one) or if they aren't GPL, then download from their site (obviously). As far as choosing which prolog you run, they all go by different names (:)) so if that's not exactly what you want, then perhaps you could clarify.  Installation is going to be what it is: if you want multiple Prolog implementations, they're going to require the space they need, but I don't think any of them are huge.

Comment: The side-by-side versions is the tricky one. For Ruby, there's a tool called `rvm` (Ruby version manager) that enables a developer to load as many versioned Ruby environments as they wish. It works really well and I can work on different projects that have different version requirements. Each is maintained under it's own subfolder from the home directory under `.rvm` and is selected with a command that resets the command/lib search paths. Sounds like you need something like that for Prolog, but I'm not aware of such a tool and not sure what overlap problems might exist otherwise.

Comment: @lurker. Packages (PPA for Ubuntu) for the development branch, like SWI-Prolog has them, would be ideal. Or maybe git. But I'd rather not to use a different tool for each Prolog implementation...

Comment: I think [Logtalk](http://logtalk.org/compatibility.html) *uses* most of the required features you want, so could be worth to take a look... I have installed SWI,GProlog,YAP,my own Intlog, but in the end I always use SWI

Comment: IMO, the most significant issue here is that most of the implementations are not packaged in standard ways, GNU and SWI being the exception. If they were, you could use GNU stow and install them unprivileged (which is what I have done with SWI and in the past GNU at my work). XSB and Yap are egregious offenders here and the problem should be fixed upstream with them.

Comment: @DanielLyons. Thanks for your input! What would be a reasonable approach? What's plan a, plan b, ...? Maybe something based on aws ec2?

Comment: EC2 specifically and AWS generally aren't going to help you do anything at all with your local machine. IMO the best solution would be to get the upstreams to provide standard-ish looking modern open-source Unix packages, meaning source code with an Autoconf or similar script. Most Unix/Linux distributions we have today know how to convert that into the native local package format with little fuss. If your INSTALL file is non-standard, a lot of distributions will exclude you. Doubly-so if suid-root files are involved or fancy privileges are needed to build.

Comment: Plan B or C here would be to use Vagrant or Docker to package up VMs or containers with a minimal Linux distribution (Alpine Linux comes to mind) and one Prolog implementation. You can script installation this way, and the effect (on OSes that can execute Docker especially) would be like having a privilege-separated Prolog process running with your implementation du jour. With Vagrant, it's really in a virtual machine and it's a bit thicker. Docker is lighter-weight.